# Processing a file while its being uploaded in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

My Application requires client to upload a Huge file through a Form . Currently , django stores the file in temp folder and my view function  gets hit only after the whole file is uploaded where i can access the file.

My requirement is to be able to get uploaded chunks as soon as they arrive at the server so that i can start the processing .

I checked , there is streaming HTTP response but nothing for HTTP request (POST from client)

Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers)'s how to write your own upload handler. And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers)'s a brief introduction in Django upload handlers.